# Unique solution first order differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation given by $ \frac{1}{c^2}=f(\beta)(f'(\beta)^2+1)$, where c ist a positive constant and we have that at some point $\beta'$, we have $f(\beta')=y>0$. Now the question is whether each solution to this ODE is unique, if we do not want to consider solution that are constant on an interval. 
My problem is the following: obviously there are plenty of solutions to this ODE that describe functions that are somehow constant on some interval. but what is about solutions that are not constant on an interval. Is there more than one solution to this equation? How could I proof this? I mean the problem is, that one cannot write this ODE as a function of f' directly, so theorems like Picard Lindelöf will not apply to this ODE. Unfortunately I do not know many theorems about ODEs so maybe this question is an easy one.

Comment: You don't have the uniqueness of ODE, let alone its solutions...

Comment: sorry, I do not understand your remark, could you say it differently?

Comment: You have more than one ODE -- actually two: $f'(\beta)=\pm \sqrt{1/(c^2 f(\beta))-1}$.

Comment: so what should this be telling me?

Comment: It should be telling you that this fact (two ODEs) answers your question about uniqueness (negatively).

Comment: I am not sure about this. take $y'(t)^2+y(t)^2=0$ as an example. this equationhas a unique solution as it gives you y''(t)=-y(t) by differentiation.

Comment: $y'^2+y^2=0$ has only trivial solution $y=0$.

Comment: if this is the case, then this is a unique one. so how does your statement restrict the existence of unique solutions?